# Make "case statement" iterate with unknown length array

Tags: bash

I need to set a number of options to increase the power of the ifaces connected to the system.

```
echo "Options: "
echo "[0] Back"

for i in "${#INTERFACES[@]}"; do
    echo "[ $(($i+1)) ] set ${INTERFACE[$i]} to max power"
done

echo "[ $(($i{#INTERFACES[@]}+1)) ] set ALL ifaces to max power"
echo ""
```

This code give me this menu:

```
Options: 
[0] Back
[1] Set wlan0 to max power
[2] Set wlan1 to max power
[3] set ALL ifaces to max power
```

`${INTERFACES[@]}` has 2 items in this example ("wlan0" "wlan1") but could be any number. And here comes my problem:

```
read -p "Input from user: " USER_INPUT
case $USER_INPUT in
    [0]* ) function_back; break;;
# I need here iterate over items in ${INTERFACES[@]}. 1) and 2) for wlan0 and wlan1 respectively.
    [3]* function_ALL; break;;
```

I tried with "select" but i havent succeeded because it not allow me to start with 0) option and change the statement of the different options, i just got this:

```
1) wlan0
2) wlan1
```

I need to stick with the initial idea, so a solution with "case" would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `for i in "${!interfaces[@]}"; do printf '%d) %s\n' "$i" "${interfaces[$i]}"; done`

Comment: `[[ -v INTERFACES[$USER_INPUT] ]] && echo "USER_INPUT was a valid INTERFACE"`

Comment: Why `[0]*` / `[3]*` instead of `0` / `3` ? (and you forgot the second `)`

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks for your reply, but thats not what im looking for exactly.

Comment: @jhnc Thanks! Im pretty new in bash. Your answer gave me an idea. Maybe its a bit silly but i didnt know that "case" could use ranges, so im using now the lenght of "INTERFACE". Im going to edit now. Now its working.

Comment: `for i in "${!interfaces[@]}"; do case "${interfaces[$i]}" in ${interfaces[$user_input]}) echo "$user_input is a ok.!";; esac; done`

Comment: I wouldn't use `case` for this. Is there a particular reason you're convinced it's the right tool for the job? Just set up an array with the numbers as your keys and the values as your indexes; you don't *need* a `case` to do the lookup at all, then.

Comment: And if you have your own solution, use the *Add an Answer* button to add it **as an answer**; don't edit it into the question. (Only once you accept an answer that's added *as an answer* will your question be marked solved).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for your advice. Im pretty new in this site but ill try my best ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to use `select`:

```
interfaces=(wlan0 wlan1)
options=(Back)
for ifc in "${interfaces[@]}"; do
    options+=("Set $ifc to max power")
done
options+=("set ALL ifaces to max power")

functions=(function_back function_1 function_2 function_ALL)

function_back () { echo "back"; }
function_1 () { echo "setting 1"; }
function_2 () { echo "setting 2"; }
function_ALL () { echo "setting all"; }



select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    "${functions[$REPLY]}"
    break
done
```

There are two parallel arrays: `options` holds the strings to display in the menu, and `functions` stores the name of the corresponding function to run.

In this `select` statement, we'll assume the user only types on of the option numbers; that number is stored in `REPLY` (`opt` holds the value from `options` corresponding to that number), so we index `functions` with `REPLY` to get the name of the function to call, then call it. After it returns, we break.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution that best suits what I was looking for.

As I explained at the beginning of my question, I needed to use `case` simply in order to get user input without displaying options directly from `case`, but from the menu built from `echo` in first place. In this way I can keep the first option as `0` instead of `1`, as `select` requires. But this answer has helped me a lot to understand how `select` works and I will surely be able to use it in the near future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution @chepner has given me. This is the block that I am using to keep the menu built with `echo` at first.

```
#GET INPUT USER
read -p "Input from user: " USER_INPUT

#"0" WILL BE ALWAYS FOR BACK FUNCTION
if (( "$USER_INPUT" == "0" ))
then
     echo "back"

#"1" WILL BE ALWAYS THE FIRST INTERFACE, AND THE LAST INTERFACE WILL BE THE LENGTH OF $INTERFACES[@]
elif (( "$USER_INPUT" <= "${#INTERFACES[@]}" ))
then
     echo "iface = ${INTERFACES[$(($USER_INPUT-1))]}"

#THE LENGTH OF $INTERFACES[@]+1 WILL BE ALWAYS THE "ALL" OPTION
elif (( "$USER_INPUT" == "$((${#INTERFACES[@]}+1))" ))
then
     echo "all"

#EVERYTHING ELSE WILL BE INVALID
else
     echo "Invalid input!"
fi
```